# Programmatically add key mappings in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'm creating several commands programmatically and want to avoid having to add key mappings for them explicitly in keymap.cson.

The Flight Manual page for Keymap Manager shows an [add](https://flight-manual.atom.io/api/v1.39.1/KeymapManager/#instance-add) method. It doesn't give an example of how to actually use this method, so my guess is that this should work:

```
atom.keymaps.add('atom-text-editor',{'alt-1':'custom:my-command'});
```

However, this does not appear to work. When I run this in the developer console, I get this message:

```
Encountered an invalid key binding when adding key bindings from 'atom-text-editor' 'custom:my-command'.
```

I got this message even if I changed `alt` to `ctrl`.

What does the correct method call on `atom.keymaps` look like.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the docs are not detailed enough. However, through trial and error, I managed to figure it out:

```js
atom.keymaps.add('foo', {
    'atom-text-editor' : {
        'alt-1': 'custom:my-command',
        '#': 'application:about'
        // etc
    }
});
```

Explanation:

```
atom.keymaps.add(source, bindings, priority);
```

The `source` argument is not the same as what is referred to as the `selector` in Atom speak. Instead, it's an identifier that can be used to remove the keybindings, should you wish to (except it seems they haven't actually implemented a remove method!).

Instead, the selector should go inside the `bindings` argument, as shown above.